# How to create an index on table creation?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Let's say two statements:

```
CREATE TABLE words (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    word VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_word ON words(word);
```

Can I set the index in the schema definition? (I don't want to set `word` as primary key) I'm working on Sqlite and Mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
word varchar(25),
key (word)
```

You could also say `index (word)` -- they are synonymous.  If you want to name the key, you can say

```
key `key_name` (word)
```

[`CREATE TABLE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

Comment: I had googled 'create table on index creation' and the only results I got where the 'create index' statement.. Thanks!